# Authenticate external resource say html page before loading in my windows phone app

Tags: c#, android, webview, uwp, wkwebview

How to pass data to and pro from the html page that i load in webview.
I want to pass user name/password to the html from my app authenticate the page and then load it within the app. And i even want to pass in some data to the static page

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided your html page. So I tried to create a simple html page according to your description.

In uwp application you could use `InvokeScriptAsync` method to pass data to html page. And the invoked script can return only string values.

For example, if the content of a web view named MyWebView contains a function named `Login` that takes two parameters, you can invoke it like this.

**Html Page**

```
<body >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Login(account, psw) {
            document.getElementById('act').innerText = account;
            document.getElementById('psw').innerText = psw;
        }
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="act" name="accout"/>
    <input type="text" id="psw" name="password"/>
</body>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private async void PassDataBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {     
     string[] args = { "account", "psw" };
     string returnValue = await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("Login", args);
 }
```

If you did not know the html page content you could use `InvokeScriptAsync` with the JavaScript eval function to inject content into the web page.

```
 private async void PassDataBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      string functionString = String.Format("document.getElementById('act').innerText = '{0}';  document.getElementById('psw').innerText = '{1}'   ", "Nico","PSW");
      await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
 }
```

For more detail please refer to official document about [Web view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/web-view). If this workaround does not apply to your scenario, please share more detail about your html page

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really works.  When the Html is completely loaded then i can call the script on the page. My requirement is to verify the user who wants to load html from html before loading it

Comment: I have a little confused about your requirement , How do you inject javascript before loaded html?